# Play framework + ebean: Nested models are being saved as null

Tags: java, playframework, persistence, ebean

I think this is a simple problem: 
I have two models, for example;

```
@Entity
case class User(name: String, email: String) extends Model {
  @Id
  var id: Int = 0
}
```

And then;

```
@Entity
case class Task(
  subject: String, 
  body: String, 
  @ManyToOne
  user: User) extends Model {
  @Id
  var id: Int = 0
}
```

What I see is that when I fetch all Tasks from the database (`find().all()`), I see that `user = null` for all the Tasks, while debugging, if I set a breakpoint at `newTask.save()`, I see that the user field of that instance is correctly set.

What's wrong with this?

Comment: From [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaEbean): "Enhancement of direct Ebean field access (enabling lazy loading) is only applied to Java classes, not to Scala". Use getters/setters.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Salem, basically, the [link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaEbean) pointed out by him suffices to know what is going on – and often this can be a bit confusing.

What I did was define a getter/setter for the references;
So something like this in `Task` will do;

```
@Entity
case class Task (subject: String, body: String) {
  val userId: Int = 0
  // setter
  def user_= (user: User) = userId = user.id
  // getter
  def user:User = {
    User.find().byId(userId) // ensure find() is defined in the companion object
  }
}
```